# typolink: set page type for internal links on condition

Tags: typo3, typoscript

how can i create a typolink which:

- reads it's target from a column in `tt_content` (like `header_link` f.e.)
- applies a page type to internal links, but obviously not to external links

f.e., given the values `42` and `https://x.org` in `header_link` the desired links should look like:

```
/<path_to_page_id 42>?type=5
https://x.org
```

i can't figure out how to apply the page type on the condition internal/external link. this is what i got:

```
text = TEXT
text.value = click here ;-)

text.stdWrap.typolink {
  parameter.field = header_link

  # following line should only apply if `header_link` is an internal link
  parameter.wrap = |,5
}
```

**edit to clarify**:
above code produces:

```
/<path_to_page_id 42>?type=5
https://x.org,5                 <-- not what i want
```

how do i get the page type for internal links and leave external links untouched?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation to the TSREF for typolink
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink/Index.html

adding a page type:

```
lib.sampleLink = TEXT
lib.sampleLink.value = Open Page 25 with Type 800 in a new window
lib.sampleLink.typolink.parameter = 25,800 _blank
```

Comment: i know, page type is set after the comma, that's what the `wrap` in my code does. problem with your approach: page id (25) is hardcoded, and not read from db.